# Discord.js bot Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to implement for my discord server and my discord bot a possibility to send a PM message to a lot of users.

I created something like this:

```
client.on("message", message => {
  
  mentiondm = message.mentions.users.first();
  mentionMessage = message.content.slice(22)
  mentiondm.send(mentionMessage);
  console.log('Message Sent!')
  
})
```

It's working for first mentioned user, message is sending but there are several problems:

- after sending first message bot is crashing down with this error `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`
- I tried to change `message.mentions.users` to `message.mentions.roles` but then message is not sending.

There is a way to do my functionality better or at least upgrade this what I have here to working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it tries to get the first mentioned user from the bot's message too. Check if the message author is a bot and if it is, don't send the message.

Also, try to check if there is someone mentioned and if not, simply return.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  let mentionDM = message.mentions.users.first();

  if (!mentionDM)
    return console.log('No mentioned user');

  let mentionMessage = message.content.slice(22);

  mentionDM.send(mentionMessage);
  console.log('Message Sent!');
});
```

Comment: Can u help me to change a first mention user to a whole role or just a certain number of users?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to mention role and bot will send a PM to every user from role

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234966/discussion-between-zsolt-meszaros-and-karol-wisniewski).